# Find minimum bounding rectangle of an arc

Tags: analytic-geometry

How do you find the minimum bounding rectangle of a circular arc ?
You are given the starting point, ending point and another point on the arc.

With these points, I've found out the co-ordinates for the centre of the circle and the radius. I'm unsure how to proceed from here though. The rectangle must be axis aligned.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find the highest and lowest, leftmost and rightmost points in your arc.  These points will either be the endpoints of your arc, or, if they are included in your arc, the extreme points of the circle.

Comment: What does `extreme points` of a circle mean ?

Comment: The greatest and least values for $x$ and $y$